# Accessing Android service using context

Tags: java, android, android-service

For deisgn reason, I  have to implement Android sensor specific  code into the class with `extends Service`. For example,

```
public class SmokeService extends Service implements ISmokeDetector {

    SensorManager mySensorManager;
    Sensor myProximitySensor;
    private double currentLightReading;
    private Context myContext;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }   

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

    mySensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
myProximitySensor = mySensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_PROXIMITY);
mySensorManager.registerListener(proximitySensorEventListener, myProximitySensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);

    }

    SensorEventListener proximitySensorEventListener = new SensorEventListener() {
        @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

    }
    };

    @Override
    public SmokePresenceStruct getsmokePresence() {

              return new SmokePresenceStruct(true, timestamp);

        }

    @Override
    public void getsmokePresence(ListenersmokePresence handler) {
          handler.onNewsmokePresence(this.getsmokePresence());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEventDriven() {

    }
}
```

My question is that "**Is there any way to start the above service through non Android Java class?** " Let's say I have a java class, who has Context and it want to start this service. For example :

```
public class AndroidSmokeDetector {

    Context myContext;

    public AndroidSmokeDetector(Context context, Object obj) {
        //super(context);
        this.myContext = context;

    }
}
```

Could please suggest me the way of  interacting with the service through the `AndroidSmokeDetector` class. Assuming that  I will get context from `MainActivity` ?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes in your AndroidSmokeDetector just call

```
myContext.startService(myContext, SmokeService.class);
```

Comment: But AndroidSmokeDetector class is not extended with Activity. So, I guess it is not possible to call. I have tried this, but it is not  possible with my limited Android knowledge.

Comment: @PankeshPatel pass the activity context to the constructor of the AndroidSmokeDetector class.

Comment: You have a constructor that have a context param, as long as you have a context it is OK.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to start the above service through non Android Java
>   class?

**Option 1 :**

Yes, you will need to use class constructor for getting Context in non Activity class.do it as:

```
public class AndroidSmokeDetector {
    Context myContext;

    public AndroidSmokeDetector(Context context, Object obj) {
        //super(context);
        this.myContext = context;
    }
 //...
}
```

use `myContext` for starting service from `AndroidSmokeDetector` class as:

```
myContext.startService(myContext, SmokeService.class);
```

send `MainActivity` Activity context by using `AndroidSmokeDetector` class constructor as:

```
AndroidSmokeDetector objsmokeclass=new AndroidSmokeDetector(MainActivity.this);
```

**Option 2 :**

instead of using class constructor you can create an parametrized method for starting Service from non Activity class.as:

```
public class AndroidSmokeDetector {

   public void startServiceFromNonActivityClass(Context myContext){

      //start service here...
     myContext.startService(myContext, SmokeService.class);
   }
 //...
}
```

now just call method for starting service by passing current context from Activity as:

```
AndroidSmokeDetector objsmokeclass=new AndroidSmokeDetector();
objsmokeclass.startServiceFromNonActivityClass(MainActivity.this);
```